# Building regex for special case

Tags: c#, regex

My text can contain values like these:-

1. `[Other]`
2. `A,B,[Other]`
3. `[Other][N/A]`
4. `[Other]Hello`
5. `[Other]Hello,baby`

I want a regex expression which can satisfy only case 4 and 5. For the first three cases, it should fail. In my case, [Other] is fixed in the string value. We can simplify the regex with hardcode of [Other]. For case, event text [N/A] is fixed, so that makes it different from case 4 and 5.

- The string must start with word [Other]. 
  The string must not contain word [N/A]. 
  The string must not have word [Other] alone.

Pls help and suggest the regex expression.

For testing, pls use http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: You need to show what you've done and explain a bit better what you want (e.g. The string must start with `[Other]Hello` or the string must start with `[Other]` but not have `[N/A]`)

Comment: So `[Other][NA]` should be matched?

Comment: [Other][NA] should not be matched.

Comment: Why not? You said `[N/A]` is a special case. So why shouldn't `[Other][NA]` match?

Comment: i don't the regex success with [Other][N/A]. That why i want it to fail.  I tried with this expression [Other][^[N\/A]].* but it does not fail case 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what exactly you want to match, but this works for your case

```
^\[Other\][^\[]+$
```

Which breaks down like... start (`^`) followed by the string `[Other]` (escaped) followed by not `[` (`[^\[]`) one or more times (`+`) followed by end (`$`)

---

EDIT
Or a more specific version (as per comment) is as above, but second half has not `[` followed by not `N` followed by not `\` optionally, followed by not `A` optionally, followed by not `]` followed by zero or more of any character (`.*`) end (`$`)

```
^\[Other\][^\[][^\N]?[^\\]?[^A]?[^\]]?.*$
```

Comment: i tried with this \[Other\][^\[N\/A\]].* But it is not failing case 1 and 2. And i want to cover these two cases also.

Comment: It works, just try putting your test values in one at a time, and don't forget that newlines are counted as a character... http://regexr.com?2v5ke

Comment: this one works for me, i changed it to more specific one. ^\[Other\][^\[N\/A\]]+$

Comment: That regex is not quite doing what you expect... I will update my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this `regex`:

```
^\[[^\]]+\][a-zA-Z,]+$
```